# Is this an Extension or Helper Method in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am confused about which is which. Can someone explain the difference between the two.

For example is the following which returns a MvcHtmlString an extension or a helper method?

```
public static class LinkExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString HdrLinks(
        this HtmlHelper helper, 
        string topLink, 
        string subLink, 
        System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user)
    {
    etc ...
```

How about this:

```
    public static class Slug
{
    public static string Generate(string phrase, int maxLength = 50)
    {
        string str = RemoveAccent(phrase).ToLower();
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^a-z0-9\s-]", " ");
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[\s-]+", " ").Trim();
        str = str.Substring(0, str.Length <= maxLength ? str.Length : maxLength).Trim();
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "-");
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know about MVC's "helper" methods, but "helper" doesn't mean anything from an OO or architectural standpoint, and is a bad naming convention to use.  Avoid it when you can, but feel free to use existing libraries/code that uses that bad name.  If MVC is generating methods called "helper", don't try to correct it - just don't pile on top of the existing bad naming.  For example, the extension methods that MS added to `IEnumerable` types are called "Linq", not "EnumerableHelper".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not helper methods, they are called HTML helpers.There is no 'helper method' implementation in C#. HTML helpers are implemented as extension methods. You can see extension methods are static methods with a this clause before first parameter. HTML helpers makes it easier to generate html tags.

Comment: So in a typical MVC configuration would these be stored in the /Helpers directory or /ExtensionMethods ? Should I put them in different directories for clarity?

Comment: Those come with MVC are in System.Web.Mvc.Html namespace. You can store your custom helpers in anywhere you want.

Comment: You may want to consider registering the namespace in which your extension method code (`LinkExtensions` above) is declared, in your web.config. In the web.config file, you would add lines like this to your `<namespaces>` section: `<add namespace="My.Namespace"/>`. Otherwise, you won't be able to use your helper extension methods without a @using or @import in your view code.

Comment: I am registering in web.config but still wondering what the convention is for directory placement in MVC.

Comment: You can check [this video](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/creating-custom-html-helpers) and see if you are missing something

Answer (score 0):

```
public static MvcHtmlString HdrLinks(this HtmlHelper helper, string topLink)
```

is both a C# extension method and an html helper method for use in ASP.NET MCV Views:

```
//Example of a call as an extension method:

var helper = new HtmlHelper(...);
var result = helper.HdrLinks(topLink);

//Example of a call as a helper method in an MVC razor view:
@Html.HdrLinks(topLink)
```

The following is a "standard" static C# method:

```
public static class Slug {
  public static string Generate(string phrase, int maxLength = 50)
}

//Example of call:

var phrase = "Freech Alpes are the surfer's best spot"
var result = Slug.Generate(phrase);
```

Static methods are called without a class instance. It is a special dummy construct to group functions.