# Storing the results of Html.Action call in a dictionary? (ASP.NET MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC3 app, and I'd like to make a call from the view to the controller and store that information as a Dictionary.

**Controller code:**

```
public Dictionary<string,int> foo()
{
    Dictionary<string,int> bar = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    bar.Add("test",100);
    return bar;
}
```

**View code:**

```
@{ Dictionary<string,int> foobar = Html.Action("foo"); }
...
<div>@foobar["test"]</div>
```

I can get the view to work if I use `var foobar = Html.Action("foo");`, but then it just says that foobar is of type `System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString`, so I can't do much with it.

Is there any built-in functionality that I'm missing, or should I just use something like a JSON result for this?

**EDIT: Additional Info**

It should be noted also, that in the VS2010 debugger, it recognizes foobar properly as `{System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.Int32]}`, so the issue is that foobar isn't resolving correctly. The error thrown is:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] 
to an expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString'
```

**EDIT 2**

These are the errors that came with casting the result to a dictionary:

`Url.Action("foo").ToDictionary<string,int>();` returned `CS1501: No overload for method 'ToDictionary' takes 0 arguments` for obvious reasons, but the VS2010 debugger recognizes that the result is a Dictionary:

[image: Bug 1]

But when I add parameters (`Url.Action("foo").ToDictionary<string,int>(x=>x);`), it stops recognizing that it is a dictionary, although I'm not sure those are the proper params (it's based off what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611126/using-todictionary).

[image: Bug 2]

Comment: Why you want to call controller from view to get dictionary? What you are trying to achieve? I feel you are trying to achieve something in completely wrong way.

Comment: The code above is vastly simplified for troubleshooting. The idea behind it is that the view takes in values from sliders and passes those to the controller, and the controller recalculates and updates several scores that are on the view. There is a significant calculation requirement, so I'd rather have that run on the server rather than the local instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try as much as possible to keep views dumb. The controller has to push the data to the view. For some reason if you want to perform call a function that performs complex calculations then a better idea would be create a separate static class and move the function from controller to that class. The `Html.Action` is for entirely a different purpose. Your controllers should always return action results not dictionaries or other types.

Answer (score 0):

A call to Html.Action("foo") is supposed to return a string. What this is doing is calling an action method that renders the child view as a string. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721266

You could call a static utility method , see [Is this an Extension or Helper Method in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178648/is-this-an-extension-or-helper-method-in-mvc3)

Comment: The method references a database context instance, so I'm not sure I can make static work.